# react js not lilting me to type in any of the input fields ( I tried to remove the value props but still not working)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input, react-bootstrap

I am doing a simple Contact Form using React Js , i have created the component using react bootstrap but when i try to type in the input fields, I dons not change at all.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col,Form , Button} from "react-bootstrap";
import Particle from "./Particle";
import "../style.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

function ContactMe(){
   const [name, setname] = useState("");

function handelChange(e){
    const newName = e.target.value;
    setname(newName);
    console.log(newName);
}
return (
    <Container fluid className="about-section">
    <Particle />
    <Container>
<h1>Contact Me form </h1>

<Container className="d-flex flex-column">
<Form>
 <label>Name</label>
<Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" onChange={handelChange} value={name}/>
<label>Email</label>
<Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter your Email" />
<label>Message</label>
<Form.Control as="textarea" type="text" placeholder="Enter your message" />
<Button variant="outline-danger mt-5 ">Danger</Button>

</Form>
</Container>

</Container>
</Container>
);
```

}

export default ContactMe;`

I have tried to remove the `value={name}` and it didnt work as well

Comment: I have tried to use the `<input></input>` and <Form.Input> and it didnt work as well

Comment: If you remove the `onChange` and `value` attributes, are you able to input anything inside the text field or does it stay blank?

Answer (score 0):

1. Why arent you using a ***TextInput*** component instead of a ***Form.Control***?
2. The value prop should have the updated state value, but it seems like you are returning the inital value of the state.

Maybe you can try creating a prototype for users with properties you need *-in this case value "name"-* , and create a new user object every time the form is submitted.

Just giving my thoughts I am beginner also. Dont roast me lol.